# Single Object in Mbox State tree?

Tags: mobx-state-tree

If I made a store(RegistrationStore) and there is only 1 company created what type do I use?

```
  .model("RegistrationStore", {
    company: types.optional(????)
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of your requirements.
E.g. if you should store some properties for companies (name, address, ...) then it is better to create separate `Company` model.

In that case you may have following variant (creates new empty company by default):

```
.model("RegistrationStore", {
  company: types.optional(Company, Company.create())
})
```

or this variant (null value by default):

```
.model("RegistrationStore", {
  company: types.maybe(Company)
})
```